# How to remove a screw from electrical box?

Tags: screws

I am replacing one of the light switches at home. The bottom screw that fastens the switch to the electrical box is half way out, but refuses to come out any more, no matter how hard I rotate the screw driver. My guess is that either the screw or the hole in the electrical box is stripped. Is there any way I can get it out?

Comment: I agree. Cut off the head and run it through. you know clockwise. may be able to avoid re-tapping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to get it out is muscle. Not much else.  Use a vice grip type plier to get it out.  If it breaks off go to the other side.   Some people say tighten it up into a drill and use the drill to get it out.  When you get it out then re-tap the screw hole.  In the U.S. electrical boxes are 6/32 and most DIY's and electrical wholesalers sell taps for this reason.  Good Luck.